# Can I host a web site on my home computer?

Tags: web, oracle-apex

I have developed a web application in Oracle APEX, which I have thoroughly tested and it is running fine on my home PC. I also have bought a domain name. Now I want to know how can I connect that domain name to my home computer, so that anyone on internet can see my site ?

For the time being, just forget about the domain name. I just want to know how can I connect to my home server from internet using just the IP address (no domain required) of my computer? if anyone can reach my computer, we will have access to my web server/site.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would be better on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You might try asking on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). You'll be unlikely to get a response on Server Fault as they are aimed at professionals so home-hosted sites are out of scope.

Comment: You really shouldn't. A home network almost certainly can't handle the issues surrounding heavy traffic, downtime, and most importantly: security.

Comment: As [@Aberrant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/982107/aberrant) says, there's security concerns to keep in mind.  That being said, it it may be worth experimenting with it.  Most of us would agree though that whatever you set up shouldn't be left open and running 24/7 unless additional effort is made to harden your exposed server resource.

Comment: Some alternate ideas: you can verify your app from the outside world at Oracle's hosted space: apex.oracle.com (free, but try only); If you're looking to deploy your app to a real0world setting, Oracle also has a cloud service for paid Oracle Apex instances... for a monthly fee.

Comment: You might want to check with your ISP, it may be against their TOS to host a web site or FTP server.  Wouldn't want you to lose your home connection.

Answer (score 0):

These two links will help you get started. Its hard, but is possible. I don't know if the time is worth the couple bucks for a domain and all the support that comes with it.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/website-without-domain-name.shtml

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZqCEHRqY38

AeroVTP